# System time and file time in CUDA

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cuda

I am using the following code to calculate time in C++ coce

```
SYSTEMTIME sm;
FILETIME fm;

GetSystemTime(&sm);
SystemTimeToFileTime(&sm,&fm);

*time =  (double)(fm.dwLowDateTime / 10000000.0);
```

Now i want to calculate the same time when i am implementing CUDA version this functions are called in between CUDA kernel function. Any idea or help how i can do it. I am pretty new to cuda programing and dont know much of it.
Also can anyone tell me how to use the new operator in a `__device__` function I tried

```
maxY = new int[m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight]; 

cudaMalloc((void **)&m_labelBuf , m_imgWidth*m_imgHeight);
```

but it is giving me error

```
 calling a __host__ function("cudaMalloc") from a __global__ function("kernel_Labeling") is not allowed
```

Comment: Using the [cudaEvent API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676102/strategies-for-timing-cuda-kernels-pros-and-cons) is the most trouble-free method of timing cuda code.  You can use [device side malloc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) similarly to the way you would do it on the host, for compute capability 2.0 and newer (Fermi and newer) devices.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: thanks for the corrections and extra links.  Want to post them as an answer so you can get credit for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little bit of dynamic or pseudo-dynamic memory allocation via registers (private per-thread) and shared memory (private per-block), but it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do.

To allocate memory on the heap from device-side code, you can use C++ new operator or you can use [device-side malloc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).  This only works on Fermi and newer GPUs.

Using the [cudaEvent API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676102/strategies-for-timing-cuda-kernels-pros-and-cons) is the most trouble-free method of timing cuda code.

**EDIT:** *I've merged Robert Crovella's comments into this answer.  If he posts his comments as an answer, please vote for his instead of this one.*

Comment: You can dynamically allocate heap memory from device code.  One method already indicated is using C++ new operator.  Or you can use [device-side malloc](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations).   The limitation here is that it works on Fermi or newer i.e.  compute capability 2.0 or greater.  The limitation is not exclusive to Kepler.