# How to measure GPU vs CPU performance? Which time measurement functions?

Tags: time, cuda, gpu, measurement

What libraries or functions need to be used for an objective comparison of CPU and GPU performance? What *caveat* should be warned for the sake of an accurate evaluation?

I using an Ubuntu platform with a device having compute capability `2.1` and working with the CUDA 5 toolkit.

Comment: gettimeofday? Works for me.

Comment: for timing cuda activity, you might be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676102/strategies-for-timing-cuda-kernels-pros-and-cons/)  You should be able to find plenty of references for timing CPU-only code.

Comment: @windfinder it works for cpu measure but how about GPU measure?

Comment: For GPU measurement you can try `nvprof`: [link](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#nvprof-overview).

Answer (score 6):

I'm using the following

**CPU** - return microseconds between tic and toc with 2 microseconds of resolution

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec  init;
struct timespec  after;

void tic() { clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&init); }

double toc() {
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&after);
    double us = (after.tv_sec-init.tv_sec)*1000000.0f;
    return us+(after.tv_nsec- init.tv_nsec)/1000.0f;
}
```

**GPU**

```
float time;
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
cudaEventCreate(&start);
cudaEventCreate(&stop);
cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

// Instructions

cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
cout << setprecision (10) << "GPU Time [ms] " << time << endl;
```

**EDIT**

For a more complete answer, please see [Timing CUDA operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876624/timing-cuda-operations).